# Font size of two sites different in Chrome for Android

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am having an issue with font sizes in Chrome for Android. These two sites show different font sizes although they are using the same css files and code: [link1](http://web288.merkur.ibone.ch/klingler/) and [link2](http://web288.merkur.ibone.ch/klingler/kontakt.html).

In all other browsers I have tested, the fonts are displayed identically (Chrome for Windows, IE, Dolphin, Opera). Only Chrome for Android is having the issue?

Does anybody know why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome for Android has a feature called Font Boosting which on a site that does not have the viewport meta tag will make text that does not read well on the current scale read well.

You can disable font-boosting on a page by setting the max-height on the element that is being boosted  to > 100000px.  See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84186#c16 for more details

Answer (score 1):

This might be to do with a known Chrome for Android issue; see here:

http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs